# Is ZonePlayerId capability still working?

Tags: sonos

I wanted to try out the `Include Zone Player IDs in credentials header` [capability](http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/530). I enabled it and I still didn't receive any `zonePlayerId` in any received [soap header](http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/452).

Is there something else needed to unlock this capability, is it broken or deprecated (was added in [6.2](http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/412))?

Comment: Is it because I need to have more than one Sonos Player?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not every call receive the `zonePlayerId` in the `header`.

Here, are some of the calls that receive it:

- `getMetadata` (sometimes)
- `getMediaMetadata` (sometimes)
- `getMediaURI`
- `reportPlaySeconds`
- `reportPlayStatus`
- `setPlayedSeconds`